# Can I use jQuery mobile and Vue.js together?

Tags: jquery-mobile, vue.js

I am very inexperienced with these new web technologies.  I had a hard time with AngularJS specifically getting it to render on mobiles.  I would like to use Vue.js with some of the jQuery mobile elements.  Is it possible to mix these frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend it for the following reasons:

1. Vue.js uses its [Reactivity system](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) to manage its input bindings. jQuery mobile also modifies the UI elements for look-and-feel. If you make any change on jQuery elements (for your form elements like select drop-down, radio buttons, etc.), those changes may not be reflected within Vue component.
2. Vue.js is a well built micro framework, which produces gzipped app size of under 100kb that is well suited in mobile environments. If you mix jQuery mobile, it will push the size of your app, its memory footprint, and lead to a worse user experience in low-end phones.

Unless you have a strong reason to use jQuery mobile (like if you need touch interactions like drag, etc.), I would not recommend it.

Comment: Unfortunately my boss has it in his head that he wants Jquery Mobile and he wants it in Angular.  *shakes* head.  I am assessing my alternative approaches.  Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you just want to find mobile ui support vuejs, there is a ui list :

1. mint-ui
2. muse-ui - Material Design UI library for Vuejs 2.0
3. [vux](https://github.com/airyland/vux) - not yet support Vue@2.0 yet, but vux 2.0 will be released before 2017.

And if you do not get what you like , you would like to see [this](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#ui-components).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Note: jQuery mobile is not compatible with VUE router - it causes unexpected redirection. E.g. your SPA is located at http://localhost/test/ and VUE router + jQuery mobile causes redirection to http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

Now this is partly true. jQuery Mobile UI widgets were ported to Vuejs 2 by me, the project is here:
https://github.com/mindaugasvcs/jqm-ui.vue